# What IAM permissions are required to change audit log settings in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-iam

In our Google Cloud project, we have granted the following IAM roles to certain users, but they are unable to make changes to the audit log settings.

- Project Editor
- Logging administrator

When I try to change the default configuration of the data access audit log with a message that I do not have enough permissions.

When the project owner role was granted, the configuration could be changed, but the authority is too strong in the real environment, so owner authority cannot be granted.
Can you please tell me what privileges I need to grant to this user to be able to change the audit log settings?

Comment: I do not know the answer. I thought `roles/logging.admin` had the required permissions. What is the exact error message? What setting are you trying to change? When I have similar problems, I use the command `gcloud iam roles describe ROLE` and compare the differences. Also see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging#audit_log_permissions).

Answer (score 1):

The permissions that are used to set audit logs to ADMIN_READ, DATA_READ, or DATA_WRITE appear to be resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy, so you should be able to use any role that contains those permissions.  EG Security Admin, Project IAM Admin, Organization Administrator, etc. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles to find them all.